# Can I impute a variable using MICE so that I can use the value(s) from this imputed variable to then code another variable?

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I am working with pregnancy data where I would like to impute a variable called LABOR PRESENTATION (nomical var. with 5 categories) from several other variables but then create a variable called INDICATED PRETERM BIRTH (iPTB) (yes/no) using this imputed variable LABOR PRESENTATION and another variable called PTB (yes/no). The goal is to then do regression on this newly created iPTB variable.  So, I know how to use MICE to impute the variable but I can’t figure out how to use this variable further unless I was using it for regression.  Thanks.

This is my code so far:

```
pm <- matrix(0, nvar, nvar) # this is nvar X nvar
labor_index <- match("mode_of_delivery_2018", colnames(livebirths_df))

imputors_index <- match(c('mother_age', 'BMI', 'PARITY', 'EDUC_CAT', 'HYPER_P_L'),
                        colnames(livebirths_df))
pm[imputors_index, labor_index] <- 1

impute <- mice(livebirths_df, m=5, maxit = 20, seed = 12345, predictorMatrix = pm) 

print(impute)
impute$imp$mode_of_delivery_2018

# Complete data:
new_data <- complete(impute, action="long", include =TRUE) 

colnames(new_data) #adds 2 new columns ".imp" and ".id"

# Looking at convergence:
impute$chainMean

# potting convergence:
plot(impute) # if the variance between the imputed chains is almost equal to the variance within the chains,

Then I want to create this variable called iPTB.

livebirths_df <- livebirths_df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(iPTB = case_when((((mode_of_delivery_2018 ==0) |
                                        (mode_of_delivery_2018 ==1) |
                                        (mode_of_delivery_2018 ==3)) & PTB_ff==1) ~ 1,
                                        (mode_of_delivery_2018==2 | 
                                         mode_of_delivery_2018==4) ~0,
                                        TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA)))
```

Comment: I don't understand. You said  *"I can’t figure out how to use this variable further unless I was using it for regression"* , but you previously said *"The goal is to then do regression on this newly created iPTB variable"*, so it seems you know exactly what to do.

Comment: Thanks Robert! My last sentence there wasn't very clear.  The issue is that I want to regress iPTB but I don't want to impute it.  I want to impute mode of delivery, then use mode of delivery to make a variable called iPTB.  What I don't know is whether this variable should be created for each chain-- if yes, how? I think there is something missing in the code here.